# Need advice on coding config program and read from it

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cpi

I want to put configuration into a separate program, and read it from my business program.

There are two approach I can think out.

Approach 1):

```
const ADMIN_PUBKEY: Pubkey = pubkey!("4cqBrEJs9NL2Lt3tis8BUcgPMV6zjFjyPuNzGWfB4jeh");

#[program]
pub mod admin_program {
    use super::*;

    #[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
    pub struct StructReturn {
        pub value: u64,
        pub fee: u64,        
    }

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<ConfigInit>, value: u64, fee: u64, worker: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        let account = &mut ctx.accounts.data;
        account.value = value;
        account.fee = fee;        
        account.worker_role = worker;               
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn change_config(ctx: Context<ConfigChange>, value: u64, fee: u64) -> Result<()> {
            let account = &mut ctx.accounts.data;
            if( ctx.accounts.user.key() != account.worker_role) { // Q: is this reasonable ?
                return err!(ErrorCode::NoPermission);
            }
        account.value = value;
        account.fee = fee;        
        account.worker_role = worker;               
        Ok(())
    }
    
    pub fn get_fee(_ctx: Context<ConfigAccount>) -> Result<u64> {
        let account = &ctx.accounts.data;    
        Ok(account.fee)
    }

    pub fn get_struct(_ctx: Context<ConfigAccount>) -> Result<StructReturn> {
        let account = &ctx.accounts.data;       
        let s = StructReturn { value: account.value, fee: account.fee };
        Ok(s)
    }

    pub fn get_vec(_ctx: Context<ConfigAccount>) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
            // ...
        Ok(vec![12, 13, 14, 100, ...])
    } 
    ...
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ConfigInit<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8 + ... )]
    pub data: Account<'info, ConfigAccount>,
    #[account(mut, address = ADMIN_PUBKEY)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ConfigChange<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub data: Account<'info, ConfigAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Config<'info> {
    pub data: Account<'info, ConfigAccount>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct ConfigAccount {
    pub value: u64,
    pub fee: u64,
    pub worker_role: Pubkey,
}
```

and then call get_fee/get_struct with CPI.

Approach-2):

This way, the `config_program` is almost the same as Approach-1), but do no have `get_xxx()` method.
Then the business load the `data` account directly and deserialize it, as such :

```
let configAccount = &mut Account::<'_, ConfigAccount>::try_from(&data_account)?;
```

IMO, I prefer approach-one, first, the business program don't have to hard-code the struct of config data, second, this allow config-program to change/upgrade it account struct with affect the caller.

What's your idea?

And, all these are just in my mind, maybe in practical project, they don't do this way. Can anyone share some links to real project that use and administrate configuration program?

Thanks.